# Do different rsnapshot retains use the same hard links?

Tags: backup, rsync, incremental-backup, rsnapshot

Say I have a weekly and monthly backup configured in rsnapshot. Will the *weekly* backups create hard links to the same files created by a previous *monthly* backup (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

On every rotation (hourly, daily, weekly, monthly), rsnapshot first does a `cp -L` ("copy" with hard links only), and then runs `rsync`, which deletes the links and replaces them with new/updated files.

If no files change during your whole rotation, you store only one copy of all files, and a bunch of links to the same data on disk.

If you enable debugging (verbose output), you can see the actual commands `rsnapshot` uses.

Comment: Right, so there is technically no difference between running "rsnapshot daily" and "rsnapshot monthly" other than it places the links/files into separate subdirectories?

Comment: File-wise ... there is no difference. But "daily", usually takes the last hourly folder as daily.0, and monthly takes the last weekly folder as monthly.0. Both are just "cp -L", but the folders are from different time periods.

Comment: For example, if you have 4 hourly backups, 7 daily ones, 4 weekly and 3 monthly, the last monhtly (monthly.3) is ~4 months old. If you have 18 daily backups, the last one is just 18 days old.